# Angular update screen

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

This question is asked all over the place but no combination of $timeout, $scope.$apply etc is making any difference.

```
    $scope.checkCameraIP = function(i){

    if(i > 99)
    return;

    var ip2Check = $deviceIP.substr(0, $deviceIP.lastIndexOf(".")+1) + i;

    if(ip2Check != $deviceIP)
      Gitup.get(ip2Check, gitupCmds.getDiskSpace).then(function (response) {
        $scope.cameras.some(function (camera,index) {
              if (camera.ip == '192.168.100.0') {
                $timeout(function(){
                  camera.ip = ip2Check;
                  camera.class = 'ion-wifi balanced'; // I JUST WANT THIS TO SHOW UP!
                 // $scope.checkCamera(camera);
              })

              }
              camerasFound ++;
              if(camerasFound < $scope.cameras.length)
                $timeout(function(){$scope.checkCameraIP(ipRange++)},100);
              return true;
          });
      },function(){$scope.checkCameraIP(ipRange++)}).catch(function(e){
       console.log(e);
      });
  else
      $scope.checkCameraIP(ipRange++);
  }
```

I'm looping through IP addressses looking for cameras. When I find one I update it with the IP address on an array

```
$scope.cameras = [{
  name: '1',
  ip: '192.168.100.0',
  class: 'ion-alert-circled',
  connected: false
}, {
  name: '2',
  ip: '192.168.100.0',
  class: 'ion-alert-circled',
  connected: false
}]
```

This is shown on a list

```
<ion-list ng-controller="CamerasCtrl">
  <ion-item ng-repeat="camera in cameras">

    <label  class="item item-input">
      <i class="icon ion-camera placeholder-icon"></i>{{camera.name}} -
      <input type="text" class="block" ng-model="camera.ip" ng-change="onCameraIPChange(camera)" placeholder="{{camera.ip}}">
       <i id="connected" ng-class="camera.class"></i>

    </label>
    <div class="col text-right">
      <button ng-show="camera.connected && camera.files" class="button icon ion-android-delete" ng-click="formatCamera(camera)">
        Format camera
      </button>
    </div>

  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

I can find the cameras fine and set their data - but for the life of me I can't get the list to update on the screen.

This is running in an Ionic App on Android.

Any solutions please help!!

Comment: this is not an Android question.

Comment: OK can you stop downgrading the question I removed Android

Answer (score 0):

It seems it was because the button was outside of the scope of the controller. While it was calling the function, it wasn't updating the scopes data.

```
     <ion-list ng-controller="CamerasCtrl">

  <button class="button-block icon ion-search" ng-click="searchForCameras()">
    Find Cameras
  </button>

  <ion-item ng-repeat="camera in cameras">

    <label  class="item item-input">
      <i class="icon ion-camera placeholder-icon"></i>{{camera.name}} -
      <input type="text" class="block" ng-model="camera.ip" ng-change="onCameraIPChange(camera)" placeholder="{{camera.ip}}">
       <i id="connected" ng-class="camera.class"></i>

    </label>
    <div class="col text-right">
      <button ng-show="camera.connected && camera.files" class="button icon ion-android-delete" ng-click="formatCamera(camera)">
        Format camera
      </button>
    </div>

  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Fixed it